# Плавный offset jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим есть элемент с классом `.elem1`

Есть второй элемент с классом `.elem2`

Как плавно сделать `offset()` второго элемента (`.elem2`) к элементу (`.elem1`). Чтоб достигался эффект наложения друг на друга.

Если делать так

```
var d = $('.elem1').offset();
$('.elem2').offset({top:d.top,left:d.left});
```

То это срабатывает быстро (рывком).
Как сделать это плавно ? `animate()` сдвигает до первой границы элемента `.elem1`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let elY1 = $('.elem1').offset().top + $('.elem1').height();

$('.elem2').animate({
  top: elY1
}, 1000, 'linear');
```

```css
.elem1,
.elem2 {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.elem1 {
  background: red;
  top: 50px;
}

.elem2 {
  background: blue;
  top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="elem1"></div>
<div class="elem2"></div>
```

Comment: Не совсем то. Во первых, нет эффекта наложения, а во вторых - абсолютное позиционирование. При `display: flex` & `justify-content: space-between` это выльется в проблему.